# store foreach results into variable

Tags: php, session, foreach

I am changing a plugin that uses this code to list some info in a shopping cart

```
<?php foreach($items as $itemIndex => $item): ?>

<?php #echo $item->getItemNumber(); ?>
<?php echo $item->getFullDisplayName(); ?>
```

If I add this I can store the item info but just the last item.

```
<?php $_SESSION['mine'] = $item->getFullDisplayName(); ?>
```

How can I store all the items into `$_SESSION['mine']` so it will list all the times when I call the `$_SESSION['mine']` instead of just the last one??

Answer (score 3):

Make `$_SESSION['mine']` as array -

```
<?php $_SESSION['mine'][] = $item->getFullDisplayName(); ?>
```

Comment: for some reason I got a "Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings "

Comment: try to declare this as an array before foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($items as $itemIndex => $item): ?>
   <?php $mine[] =  $item->getFullDisplayName(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php $_SESSION['mine'] = json_encode($mine); ?>
```

Then to retrieve, you can do something like:

```
<?php $mine = json_decode($_SESSION['mine']); ?>
```

Comment: $mine just returns `ARRAY` now. If I dont do `json_decode` it gets the data, just not formatted right.